# How can i search the application name not the package name and open it?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

This is my codes in main activity..

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button bClock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);

    bClock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String packageName = "com.android.gallery3d";
            Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);

            if(intent == null) {
                Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                marketIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=packagename"));
                startActivity(marketIntent);
            }
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

And my question is if it is possible not to use the package name(com.android.gallery3d) to search all my apps?.. for example, i want to search "facebook" and I input that then search.

because if I use that package name I will not open the new installed app.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PackageManager

```
final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo ai;
try {
    ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
} catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
    ai = null;
}
final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
```

And this too

```
CharSequence c = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(info.processName,PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
```

This would return the application name as defined in `<application>` tag of its manifest.

Comment: @jvpintang anywhere in activity

Comment: I put your 1st code in my button onClick, and where do i put the 2nd code?

Comment: Because i have error "cannot resolve symbol 'context'" and "cannot resolve symbol 'info'"

Comment: At top add a variable Context context=this;

Comment: Okay. thanks. How about the "cannot resolve symbol 'info'" in your 2nd code?

Comment: Add a variable Info info;